# R- Connecting local postgresql to R

Tags: r, postgresql

I have postgres installed locally in my ubuntu. The dbname is postgres and the user name is also postgres. When I'm trying to connect this database to my R script, I'm getting an error saying-

*Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect postgres@localhost on dbname "postgres"*

Here is the command that I'm running-

> con <- dbConnect(drv, dbname = "postgres",
>                    host = "localhost", port = 5432,
>                    user = "postgres", password=pw)

I checked that this is the right command to run to make this connection and I have also used this to connect to an external server before. But somehow I'm not able to connect to my local postgres instance.

What do you think I'm missing out?

Comment: Does it work on the command-line with `psql`?

Comment: yes. I can enter my postgres by changing the user to postgres with this command:
sudo su - postgres

and then i can enter the database with the command:

psql

Here is how it looks               


ashim@ashim-Flex-3-1480:~$ sudo su - postgres
[sudo] password for ashim: 
postgres@ashim-Flex-3-1480:~$ psql
psql (9.6.1)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#

Comment: Postgres allows connecting in local mode (not over the network) as well as via network when in the same machine. Can you try explicitly setting hostname on the command line and report back? (Btw, it may be better to include that kind of output in the question; it can get relatively unreadable in a comment.)

Comment: thanks @r2evans. I have tried explicitly setting my hostname and connecting. It is still not working

Comment: That indicates (to me) that your problem is not R-related. Try confirming that your local postgres instance is actually listening on a network port; it's likely that it is configured to only allow local (non-network) connections. It's also possible that it is listening on the non-`127.0.0.1` interface, so you might try your other addresses as well. What's your OS? Is postgres running natively or in a docker container?

Comment: It works now! After setting localhost explicitly

Comment: Do you mean the R side is working, or just the command line? (If just the cmd line, please confirm the command line and arguments you used.)